# In R: efficiently convert one format (character vector) to another format (numeric matrix)

Tags: r

Using one software, I can calculate the fingerprint like this:

```
>L
[1]    "1  1:1 2:1 3:1 5:1 6:1 8:1"
[2]    "5  1:1 2:1 4:1"
[3]    "9  1:1 2:1 7:1 10:1"
```

The first value: 1, 5, 9 is the corresponding molecular names, and the remaining is the corresponding finger prints, which have a fixed length, say 10. It means that one the left of ":" is the position and on the right is the bit, where 1 indicate having this bit, and 0 is omit (indicate no bit), so I would like to restore the original format. That is for the 10 bit, every bit should have corresponding value:

L should like this, I can save L as csv format.

```
mol 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1   1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0
5   1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
9   1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1
```

Here, the L have million rows, what is the efficient way to convert the wanted format?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Update

To avoid `read.csv` just use `strsplit` and the non-exported `splitstackshape:::numMat` functions:

```
M <- strsplit(L, "\\s+|:")
cbind(mol = as.numeric(sapply(M, `[`, 1)),
    splitstackshape:::numMat(lapply(M, `[`, -1), fill=0))
```

#### Update 2: Benchmarks

For the curious....

The sample data:

```
L <- c("1  1:1 2:1 3:1 5:1 6:1 8:1",
       "5  1:1 2:1 4:1",
       "9  1:1 2:1 7:1 10:1")
M <- replicate(10000, L)
```

@thelatemail's answer:

```
fun1 <- function() {
  spl <- lapply(strsplit(M,"\\s+|:.? |:.$"),as.numeric)
  vals <- lapply(spl,"[",-1)

  data.frame(
    mol=sapply(spl,"[",1),
    t(sapply(vals, function(x) {
      out <- rep(0,max(unlist(vals)))
      out[x] <- 1
      out} ))
  )
} 

system.time(out_late <- fun1())
#    user  system elapsed 
#   98.36    1.28  100.06
head(out_late)
#   mol X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
# 1   1  1  1  1  0  1  1  0  1  0   0
# 2   5  1  1  0  1  0  0  0  0  0   0
# 3   9  1  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0   1
# 4   1  1  1  1  0  1  1  0  1  0   0
# 5   5  1  1  0  1  0  0  0  0  0   0
# 6   9  1  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0   1
```

My updated answer:

```
library(splitstackshape)
fun2 <- function() {
  M <- strsplit(M, "\\s+|:")
  cbind(mol = as.numeric(sapply(M, `[`, 1)),
        splitstackshape:::numMat(lapply(M, `[`, -1), fill=0))
}

system.time(out_ananda <- fun2())
#    user  system elapsed 
#    0.67    0.00    0.68
head(out_ananda)
#      mol 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
# [1,]   1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0  0
# [2,]   5 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0  0
# [3,]   9 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0  1
# [4,]   1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0  0
# [5,]   5 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0  0
# [6,]   9 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0  1
```

@Matthew's answer. Note that this would need to be modified to accept different `"val"` values.

```
fun3 <- function() {
  t(sapply(strsplit(M, "\\s+"), function(l) {
    mol <- as.numeric(l[1])
    names(mol) <- 'mol'
    val <- numeric(10)
    names(val) <- 1:10
    for (x in strsplit(l[-1], ":"))
      val[x[1]] <- as.numeric(x[2])
    c(mol, val)
  }))
}

system.time(out_matthew <- fun3())
#    user  system elapsed 
#    2.33    0.00    2.34
head(out_matthew)
#      mol 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
# [1,]   1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0  0
# [2,]   5 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0  0
# [3,]   9 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0  1
# [4,]   1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0  0
# [5,]   5 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0  0
# [6,]   9 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0  1
```

Comment: Thanks Ananda. It looks good. I will lean the splitstackshape package. One more questions, if the fixed length is more than 10, say 20, what should I do?

Comment: Maybe `fread` from the `data.table` package could speed things up?

Comment: @Ananda Mahto, it is important for me to specify the number of resulting columns, since the actual fingerprint number is 881, but it is not sure on the 881, there is a value.

Comment: @thelatemail, fread(text = gsub("\\s{2,}", ",", L), header = FALSE) does not work.

Comment: @Kevin, try installing the version from Github. Instructions [here](https://github.com/mrdwab/splitstackshape). Install the "devel" version.

Comment: @AnandaMahto, thanks. it works now. still, how to specify the number of resulting columns. Maybe I can manually add the largest column number. for my actual problem, it is 881. i can add: 881:0.  Thank you all.

Comment: @AnandaMahto. Your solution is so fast. You are right. it do not need specify the wanted column. Thank you.

Comment: @Kevin, in case you *do* need to specify the number of columns wanted, you can always look at the source code of the function and see what can be changed. See [**here**](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/c39c044c60bf31869f01) for an example of where I did that with this function. And, yes, matrix indexing is fast :-)

Comment: @AnandaMahto, it is so cool. Perfect. All what I need are satisfied. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

An attempt using base R functions, assuming `L` is the same as used by @Ananda.

```
spl <- lapply(strsplit(L,"\\s+|:.? |:.$"),as.numeric)
vals <- lapply(spl,"[",-1)

data.frame(
  mol=sapply(spl,"[",1),
  t(sapply(vals, function(x) {
   out <- rep(0,max(unlist(vals)))
   out[x] <- 1
   out} ))
)

#  mol X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
#1   1  1  1  1  0  1  1  0  1  0   0
#2   5  1  1  0  1  0  0  0  0  0   0
#3   9  1  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0   1
```

Comment: it is good. Using multiple apply family, hoping the speed is ok. Thank you.

Comment: It would be better to make use of matrix indexing, which `splitstackshape:::numMat` makes use of, if you are looking for a more efficient solution.

Answer (score 2):

Borrowing from thelatemail, here's an expression which returns a matrix of the proper elements.  Rather than setting the value to 1, I set the value to whatever follows the `:` character in a `for` loop.  Then the whole thing is transposed to give the format that you desire.

```
t(sapply(strsplit(L, "\\s+"), function(l) {
  # Each line is passed in as a vector, the first element is "mol"
  mol <- as.numeric(l[1])
  names(mol) <- 'mol'

  # Store the values in a vector of length 10, with names
  val <- numeric(10)
  names(val) <- 1:10

  # Split the tail of the input vector on ":" and assign to the proper slot of the output vector
  for (x in strsplit(l[-1], ":"))
     val[x[1]] <- as.numeric(x[2])

  # Put them back together
  c(mol, val)
}))

##      mol 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
## [1,]   1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0  0
## [2,]   5 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0  0
## [3,]   9 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0  1
```

Comment: Thank you. will have a try.

Comment: This [works quite efficiently](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23378717/1270695). I'm not crazy about the hard-coding of "val", but that might actually be a "feature" for the OP.

Comment: I feel the same way about the length of "val".  It would be a tiny bit faster if the names were applied only to the final resultant matrix, but probably not enough faster to worry about.

Comment: @AnandaMahto, `>  M <- strsplit(L, "\\s+|:")
>   cbind(mol = as.numeric(sapply(M, `[`, 1)),
+         splitstackshape:::numMat(lapply(M, `[`, -1), fill=0))
Error in get(name, envir = asNamespace(pkg), inherits = FALSE) : 
  object 'numMat' not found`

Comment: @MatthewLundberg, yes I want to comment on Ananda's answer.